# How to fix Mocha invisible text on Solarized Dark iTerm2 theme

Tags: vim, mocha.js, iterm2

I have this issue several times, the last thing I attempted was some patched solarized dark theme (that I can't seem to find, sorry for no link) but the problem with that was it made `vim` background really bright.

This problem was reported in 2011, so I'm guessing I'm just really bad at googling cause I can't find a solution (stumbled upon this about 5 times in the past year), nor an article about it from a recent date.

Does this problem even have a solution, if so, could you walk me through it?

This is a screenshot for those who doesn't know about this issue:

[image]

Taken from [here](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes/issues/59)

Comment: The cause is the colors used in solarized and the only long-term solution is to get rid of solarized, which is just as poorly designed today as it was years ago… and still causes the same issues.

Comment: There's no way to change mocha pallete colors? even if it's hacking into node_modules. I literally just need to see the letters w/o having to redo my whole setup... on 5 different laptops...

Comment: Mocha is not at fault, here, they use perfectly sane colors that work literally everywhere with any competently designed colorscheme. The problem is in solarized and its weird choice of colors. If you need to hack something, it's definitely solarized, not mocha.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a quick hack for **iTerm2** users, just increment the contrast a little bit.

Comment: Contrast is in Preferences -> Profiles -> Colors -> Minimum Contrast

Comment: By far the easiest hack to implement after scouring Google endlessly for this ridiculous issue.

Comment: So glad I found this.  Thanks for the quick+easy fix!!